# Background application without ui

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I am new to android development. I want to make one background application, so that it keeps running in background, and it's without any UI, and even its icon do not appear on desktop.
In short it's a stealth application.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is certainly possible. To create an app that does not have an icon in the launch pad, just remove the `Activity` with the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category from the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To implement your *background application* it strongly depends on what you want to do. You can create a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#servlife) for long running tasks, [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)s to react to specific events or  [`Activities`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife) with intent filters.

Be aware, however, that your application will be visible in both the file system and in the  settings under 'Manage Applications'.

Comment: Hi, I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time) that after installation the app is in stopped mode and does not do anything until it is started by user interaction, for example by clicking its icon. Now, if the app does not have a UI or icon, and is supposed to run as a stealth application, how does it start its service? Should the user boot the phone after installation of the app?

Answer (score 8):

Yeah it's possible look up [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Read more about the service in tutorials

[ServicesDemo - Using Android Services](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

[How Android Services Work](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/34861.aspx)

[Android Service creation and consumption](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=356)