# Android: Documentation for ContentProviders

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

One of my problem is that I often cannot find the right information/documentation for a certain thing. For this question: the Content Provider "syntax" for google applications, for example:

- gmail (=> content://gmail-ls/XXX)
- chat (=> content://im/chats)

I have seen these on certain places, but I don't know where it's documented. Where do I look this up?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ones you list are not documented. They are not part of the Android SDK. Developers should not be using them. And, at least for Gmail, developers can no longer use them as of one of the Android 2.3 patch releases.

If you do not find reference to a `ContentProvider` in the SDK (typically in the `android.provider` package), then it is not part of the SDK.

Comment: Suggestion required in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time) question, please have a look.

Comment: Good to know. I am in development on an app that reads data through the above mentioned method. So, I was wondering from where the previous developer had this information. Also: somehow this functionality stopped working => probably after the last update!