# Restart device after installation

Tags: android

Is there a way using which I can request `Android` OS to reboot after installing an application...?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK , there is no such API in android for auto reboot. you need to display a message  in diaglogbox for restart the device.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is no you can't. Android hasn't given that facility keeping in mind the security and many other purposes. So, you can do some like that when your Application is installed you can request the user to Reboot the Device before using your Application when he tries to execute your Application`.

**UPDATE**

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time) thread for having further information about it.