# Android Application Just After Boot

Tags: java, android

I did a android application which launch just after boot finishes. It works in android 2.3.3 and Android 3.1 but when i force closed application which runs  in android 3.1 and i reboot again the application doesn't come after boot ?

Comment: Yeah it won't work in 3.1 [check this Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i force closed application which runs in android 3.1 and i reboot again the application doesn't come after boot ?

Correct. On Android 3.1+, the following types of applications will not run automatically:

- Applications that are newly installed
- Applications that the user has "force stopped"

Those applications must first manually be started by the user (e.g., launching one of your activities) before they will receive any broadcast `Intents` again.

Answer (score 2):

i do it with this code and it works for me:

```
public class AutoStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
      {
         Intent serviceLauncher = new Intent(context, your.class);
         context.startService(serviceLauncher);
      }
    }
}
```

for testing you can use this in your cmd

adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Comment: thanks Boe.. i also diid the same kind of code but question is different ........