# Auto launching android app after install

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)

Is there a way to auto launch an android app after it's installed for the first time? Everything I've found online indicates that this is a no but there is one app that seems to be doing it, it's called 'Plan B'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out, it addresses the exact problem that you wish to solve:  [How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535062/1512836)