# Is there a way to start the application right after installation using some "helper application"?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an anti-theft application which is based on starting the service using a broadcast receiver for an incoming [SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS).

But if the phone is already lost, the broadcast receiver won't work when the application is remotely installed from [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) as the application has to be started at least once in order to receive broadcast for version 3.0+.

So, is there a way to start the application right after installation using some "helper application" or make broadcast receiver work for remote installation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872320/auto-launching-android-app-after-install

Comment: there is an app on google play [Android Lost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=en) which invoke the registration service for google push messages via an incoming sms without launching the app even once for version 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

Your application will need to have the uses-permission for [android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_SMS) in your manifest.

Once you have that you can register a broadcast receiver for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`.

Then you'll want to create your [receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html).

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Your receiver should extend the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and in the onReceive() method when you receive an intent for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` you want to retrieve the message and determine if it is one that you want to pay attention to.

Your code might look something like this.

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length > -1) {
                    //You have messages, do something with them here to determine if you want to look at them and other actions.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Buddy you didn't understand the problem. Please read the question again.

Comment: You are attempting to load your solution on the native application, but given the scenario provided the user would not likely have access to their application to register the phone. Instead I would do a remote install, register the receiver (done automatically) and then have the user input their number on a website or other platform. Once done, wait a few minutes send text to number they provided, [launch service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)) and then go on your merry way.

Comment: sorry didn't get you. Are you aware of the fact that broadcast receiver won't work if the application is not launched at least once  (for version 3.0 on wards).

Comment: I was not aware of this, good to know. Taking a look [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) it looks like you may be able to use [FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES) to overcome this restriction. From my understanding of reading the changes the difference is that the application is considered to be in a stopped state which causes the Broadcast Receivers to not be called, so setting the flag would cause it to be available and alleviate your problem.