# Start app (Main Activity) when .apk is Installed

Tags: android

I want to launch my application (Main Activity is a launcher activity)  automatically as soon as app installation finished for the first time. I already go through some related posts which are mostly "starting a background service" when app installed.

I just want to launch app automatically without user interaction for first time. If there is no direct and easy way to accomplish this, can we do this by any other method using 3rd party API or so?

Any assistance will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872320/auto-launching-android-app-after-install

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I Plan B does not work on Android 3.1+. My app runs on KitKat and / or above. Does this not possible?

Comment: The user has to manually launch an activity from the application.As said by Commonsware.Pls Check the comments of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8532198/5515371

Comment: do you want **your** app to be launched directly after **it** has been installed?

Comment: yes @VladMatvienko that's his question.Is it possible??

Comment: Vlad, Yes I want to launch app soon after installation completed.

Comment: no, it is not possible fortunately. It would be a great security issue if it was possible.

Comment: Thanks MujammilAhamed and Vlad Matvienk for prompt responses.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 3.1+ this is not possible due to that all installed applications remain inactive after installation. the application activation could be done manually by the user.