# Can I make my app start automatically after install?

Tags: android, kotlin

Well the title speaks for itself,

if it possible to auto start, then how do I do it?

Android API 26+

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872320/auto-launching-android-app-after-install and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time

Comment: Nope it's like 10 years old topic, don't work nowadays

Comment: Fortunately, this has not been possible in years, for security reasons.