# Show login screen when android strats booting

Tags: android

I want to show a login screen when the android devices starts booting.Web search gave some results but it is for login after bootup.

Comment: I will suggest you to read developers.android.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't load any of your Android Application when device is in the booting state. However if you are system kind of developer that loads ROM Data, then it might be possible.

As an android Developer all you can do is to make your application works only once the booting process is completed. Nothing before it.

Comment: How it is possible? Can you explain?

Comment: Its only possible if you do machine coding, like Assembly. Also you require special tool to load such code in to Android Device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED intent and show your login screen

Comment: Please read the question title and details properly.

Answer (score 0):

if you are tried to implement Device boot up means, first of all you must consider the device Android OS version. **If you have OS version 3.1+ means it won't works, the BOOT_COMPLETED permission is not called in those OS's. If you are using below 3.1 means, you can enable device boot up functionality.** Refer this question for your problem [Device Boot up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299373/how-to-run-an-andriod-appltion-when-device-start-up). I met the same problem in my application too.