# MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast not being recieved when Application is installed on SD card

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How do i start my application on startup in case when application is installed on SD card? If i application is installed on Internal memory then  using `BOOT_COMPLETED` completed broadcast we can achieve our requirements but this BOOT_COMPLETED intent is broadcasts before the media is mounted so we can not use this broadcast.

What i tried so far is, i used the another intent which is `MEDIA_MOUNTED` but don't know why broadcast is not being received.

**Here is my code**:
 AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".ui.Receiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

                <data android:scheme="package" />
                <data android:path="org.sipchat.sipua" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Receiver.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "BOOT Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            on_vpn(false);
            engine(context).register();
        } else if (intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Media is Mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            engine(context).register();
        } else if (intentAction.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)
                || intentAction.equals(ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE)
                || intentAction
                        .equals(ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_UNAVAILABLE)
                || intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED)) {
            engine(context).register();}}
```

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: have you given permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Yeah i have given that permission. Even Application is starts when its in Internal storage but what about when its in external storage?

Comment: My application is also on SDCard, and working fine. I dont think it is the problem.

Comment: Ohh i see i am currently testing on samsung galaxy 2.3.6, is there any problem with my code?

Comment: you mean Samsung Galaxy Y Duos ?

Comment: well it should work, mine is Galaxy y Duos.

Comment: Strange why it doesn't works in my case then?

Comment: @juned Have you managed to solve the problem when the MEDIA_MOUNTED broadcast is not delivered to app on SDcard?

Answer (score 0):

The application start at when the device boot up will works in android version below 3.0. For more information refer this post [Link 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299373/how-to-run-an-andriod-appltion-when-device-start-up)

Comment: Its not true boot completed is works fine in ICS too. But here my question is not about `BOOT_COMPLETED` its about `MEDIA_MOUNTED`

Comment: @juned: Once you restart your device, if your application get run?

Comment: Yeah it runs when its in internal store but while in external storage its not

Comment: @juned: Can you please guide me, because i need this exact feature in my application i tired but i failed.

Comment: yeah,why not. so in your application intent doesn't broadcasts the BOOT_COMPLETED in the devices which has the version 3.0 and higher

Comment: @juned: If i add android:installLocation="internalOnly" this in my manifest means, if it work? I used the same code which i mentioned in Link 01, but it won't work

Comment: checkout this [click here](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/ui/Receiver.java#691) i am using the same. yeah and if you didn't got anything then let me know

Comment: @juned: Hey man, thanks for your Valuable help,i add that key work in manifest it works great. thanks once again.