# Android system apps and stopped state

Tags: android

I'm trying to find somewhere in the Android doc, something that confirms this quote:

"Also, applications installed on the /system partition are not subject to 
being placed into the "stopped" state after installation."

I've seen this in two places, but I can't find any doc about system apps related to this topic. Where can I find it?

Links to the sources I foud:
[How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time) (Jeffrey Blattman's answer)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/g7-RLQscJ_E

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to find formal documentation on this subject.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I should browse android's source code to be sure of this?

Comment: You're welcome to try! :-) You might also try the `android-platform` Google Group, if you do not get a response here in a day or two.