# Service start at boot that doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, android, service, boot

I would like to know why the `Service` does not start when the device completes the boot.
I wish that when the device boots, the `Service` starts, but this does not happen because to start it I have to open the application first.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class BootService extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent2) {
        intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531926/726863

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/#tutorial_ownservice

Comment: I would like a solution to my specific problem

Comment: put the println in your broadcast and called service to check which one is not getting called broadcast or service .

Answer (score 1):

Is BootService called?

For BootService to be triggered when boot completes you need to add in your manifest:

1)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

2)

```
 <receiver android:name="BootService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: then add intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this applies also if call activity from a receiver

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the java file

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

For your application to receive the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent, you need to first run an `Activity` on the device.

Try making a dummy activity, for config, or an introduction to the app.

---

Other than that, the idea of putting log statements into the `BroadcastReceiver` and into the `Service` is a good one.

Also confirm that you have followed [djodjo's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053453/383414), as these are both correct too.