# How to implement service after installing application in android

Tags: android

I want a application , when after installation complete service start without launching activity.

Comment: And how do you exactly plan on doing this and for what reason if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Without any user interaction you can't launch your application.

As the application is put into `onStopped` state as soon it is installed on device.

(*still on devices with android vs < 3.0, it may be possible, like by listening for system broadcasts such as low battery, internet state changed, new message received, or new location change.*)

You may see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8535062/826657) for further clarifications.

Comment: Okay thanks, but if I am not writing category action launcher. Then after installation of the app never launch the activity