# Get some code working once the app get installed or when intent received after app got installed like AndroidLost

Tags: android

From what I read in other posts and in Google documentation, You can not run some code after app got installed and before the user opens it. Second approach is to make broadcast receiver that receive an intent (like SMS received) and then execute your code inside `onReceive` method but the problem here is that the app will be in stopped state until the user first opens it then it can receive any intent like SMS received for example. I found an app that does this [androidlost.com](http://androidlost.com), you install the app remotely, then send SMS remotely and so get some code executed in OnReceive method. Any way how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

According to answers and comments provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764137/2636887)

> applications installed on the /system partition are not subject to being placed into the "stopped" state after installation.
>   and it can immediately receive broadcast intents.

How to get the application installed to /system/app ??

*comment by Olle*

*As long as you have the same package name and signing you can update a system app. The update will be placed on the data partition but still have the "system" status since a previous version is available on the system partition. –  Olle Sep 21 '12 at 10:39*

**UPDATE**

Another thing you can do is add a `BOOT_COMPLETED` intent and ask the user to reboot the phone or if the device is rooted you can get the root permission and reboot the device and start the app that way

Comment: I did not get it. How to make my app installed in /system directory ?. I'm supposed to upload the app to Android Market and the user will install it from there. Is there any flags or so to use to make it installed in /System directory?

Comment: As i used to work around with the good old HTC Dream/G1 i found that most of the(or all?) the apps gets installed in the /system/app folder in android upto Gingerbread,it was actually a security loophole and got fixed in honeycomb

Comment: So we are still locked. No solution here.

Comment: I don't need any user interaction to start the app. If I will ask the user to reboot it will be easier to ask him to open the app.

Comment: well,you are stuck then

Answer (score 0):

Recently installed application on the devices which are having android version **`lower than 3.1`** will be **`able to receive`** the broadcasts.

But in the case of the devices having **`higher version than 3.1`** , they will be in stopped state and they **`will not be able to receive`** any broadcasts because `system adds FLAG_EXCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES to all broadcast intents`.
So even the `AndroidLost` will not be able to receive broadcasts in this case.

**Reference :**
[Launch Controls](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols)

Comment: I tested Android Lost in my device Samsung ACE3, Android 4.2.2 and It worked and that what makes me confused !
I installed the application remotely and send Activation SMS and then  instantly I could administrate the phone.