# How to run a service in background after updating the app

Tags: android, background-process

I have an alarm app and I have noticed that when I update/reinstall the app, the the pending alarm intents get removed. 
So I need a way to detect the application is updated, without the user starting the app.

I use broadcasts to detect phone reboots to re-register my alarms, but not sure how to detect when the app is updated.

For example, is there any way to run a service soon as the application is installed, without the user opening the app?

I have checked these but seems it is not possible. But wondering if there is any update for newer Android versions:

[Start a service automatically when app installed to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604474/start-a-service-automatically-when-app-installed-to-device)

[How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than setting an alarm, have a Manifest registered BroadcastReceiver specifically for this purpose. It can either listen to android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED (note: the word action is missing from this constant) or to android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

```
<receiver android:name="...">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"></action>
        <data android:scheme="package" android:path="com.your.package" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

After reinstall your receiver will get this message and you'll be able to start an Activity

Comment: Thank you Tariq. Didn't know about this intent. Will try this out.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

First though, let's define the BroadcastReceiver that will be executed by the alarm and will launch our IntentService:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
public static final String ACTION = "com.codepath.example.servicesdemo.alarm";

 // Triggered by the Alarm periodically (starts the service to run task)
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
context.startService(i);
 }
 }
```

Next, let's register both our IntentService and MyAlarmReceiver in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<receiver
android:name=".MyAlarmReceiver"
android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>

<service
android:name=".MyTestService"
android:exported="false" />
```

java activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
scheduleAlarm();
 }

// Setup a recurring alarm every half hour
 public void scheduleAlarm() {
 // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
 // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
 final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 
  MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// Setup periodic alarm every every half hour from this point onwards
long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) 
 this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 
 RTC_WAKEUP
// Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, 
 INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
   }
   }
```

After setting an alarm, if we ever want to cancel the alarm like this:

```
public void cancelAlarm() {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
   intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.cancel(pIntent);
 }
```

And check your manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I am not sure but please check my be it helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot A.Geek. I now need a way to find out when the application is updated, because that seems to void the pending intents.