# In an android device, where does packages-stopped.xml is stored?

Tags: android

As per the below link 
https://dzone.com/articles/depth-android-package-manager
the xml is stored /data/system/. I did find packages.xml and packages-list.xml, but packages-stopped.xml didn't find any where. I am using rooted Marshmallow OS device. Any help appreciated.

Comment: On recent android systems the packages.xml file is in /dbdata/system instead of /data/system.

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't find /dbdata

Comment: i didn't find it either. i look into android 4.4.4, android 5.0, android 6.0 and 7.0 and none of them had packages-stopped.xml. maybe it's belonged to older versions.

Comment: I am trying to launch a service during boot up. The issue is, the application have to be opened at least once before reboot, after that only the boot Completed receiver intent is receiving. But my objective is to start the service on bootup without having to launch the application. I thought that I could edit this package-stopped.xml file. Is there any idea other than this.

Comment: BroadcastReceiver will not work until the user has manually launched an activity. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856728/start-service-at-boot-without-activity) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945426/android-start-service-without-starting-application).