# Windows Mobile app to start on boot after installation without any user interaction

Tags: android, security, permissions, windows-phone, smartphone

I [read that on android all applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time), upon installation, are placed in a "stopped" state. This is the same state that the application winds up in after the user force-stops the app from the Settings application. While in this "stopped" state, the application will not run for any reason, except by a manual launch of an activity.

Is there any similar security feature implemented for Windows phones? Is it possible to start an without user interaction just after installation?

Answer (score 1):

Apps on Windows Phone run under the user's control. They cannot control their own lifecycle to start or run themselves.

There is no way to auto-start an app after install on Windows Phone.

The user must start it explicitly. Once the user has run the app the app can install a background task which can restart automatically, but the app itself cannot restart automatically if the user closes it or restarts the system. If the user switches away from the app the app will suspend and cannot resume itself without user action.

Windows Phone apps run sandboxed and cannot generally interact with or control the system outside of user control. Windows Phone provides more protection from apps (and conversely less control to apps) than Android does.

Comment: Okay, But apps like  Facebook, Viber and all requires a service running in the background always to retrieve the messages pushed from server. On reboot also these services should be running without any user interactions, right ? So I guess there should be some way to run a service (or a piece of code) on reboot on Windows device. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: No, that's not right. Apps don't need to run background services to receive push notifications for tile or toast updates. If the apps need background tasks for other reasons then (as I said previously) the background tasks can automatically restart.