# Start a Windows app without user interaction just after installation on Windows Phone

Tags: android, smartphone, boot, windows-phone

I [read that on android all applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time), upon installation, are placed in a "stopped" state. This is the same state that the application winds up in after the user force-stops the app from the Settings application. While in this "stopped" state, the application will not run for any reason, except by a manual launch of an activity.

Is there any similar security feature implemented for Windows phones? Is it possible to start an without user interaction just after installation?

Comment: Android apps can configure your phone to send an `Intent` to auto-launch a service in the background without the user knowing.  It requires a specific permission, but lets be honest most people just click yes.

Comment: @raz, According to the link I mentioned above, every app will be in "stopped" as in "inactive" state just after installation. While in "stopped" state app cannot receive any broadcast and so it is not possible to do a auto-launch. Which permission are you talking about?

Comment: @raz Also, to send a Intent to auto-launch app has to running first, right. That is the problem. I couldn't find any permission to achieve this. Looks like a good security measure.

Comment: @raz, On boot Android system will send a "BOOT_COMPLETED" broadcast to all "ACTIVE" apps. From Android 3+ version they added a new security mechanism to Android which is my question is about. It is explained here [1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols) [2](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/activating-applications/). So in order to receive any such broadcast messages and start service on background app should be in "active" state. And app goes to "active" state only user launches it manually one time after installation.

Comment: Ah that's interesting, I learned something today!

Comment: @raz, yeah I am surprised too! I would like to know whether Windows also has similar security mechanism!