# Is App-Code executed upon installation via Play-Store?

Tags: android

Is it possible that an App that is installed via Play-Store is executed upon installation without user interaction (or some code of it)? Or is it mandatory to use "Open" or to tap the icon directly?

I ask because Android Privacy Settings are only changeable after installation, so I assume between the time of Installation and the Time I change the Privacy Settings an app that is executed directly upon installation could exploit that (read the adress book for example).

Comment: It could happen if by coincidence you reboot and the app has the autostart permission, I guess.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul is there any such permission???

Comment: @AnswerDroid: I meant autostart, seems to be `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Answer (score 1):

No, not from Playstore atleast. Google doesn't give root permission to app developers (Only download from trusted sources).

Comment: hy, i am trying to convince a friend, that apps cant access data between install and first execution. this answers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time convince me, but not my friend. does anyone know of a simple official explanation of google bout that ? thx