# Retrieving Android_Id on the moment user installs the app

Tags: java, android, development-environment

how can i retrieve some data(for eg.Android ID) in android app on the moment user installs the app.In other words,i want to save Adnroid_ID even when user haven't even opened the app. Thanks in advance.
P.S. I already have the code for retrieving Android_ID(No need for that)

Comment: what do you want from getting to Android_Id at installation time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer which answers a similar query [How to start a Service when .apk is Installed for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531926/how-to-start-a-service-when-apk-is-installed-for-the-first-time/8535062#8535062)

In short, it is not possible to do anything till the app is started.