# Making a mobile app that just runs a specific python script

Tags: python, android, pydroid

I want to run a python script that I've made on a phone but as its standalone application.

Is there a way to use pydroid to make my script its standalone application. When you launch my app it has pydroid under the hood that just executes my script and nothing else.

I don't need a UI, I just need to command line interface provided by default in pydroid when it runs python.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file you could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370659/background-application-without-ui) other thread. If you go the route of trying to edit the source code files you may need to make sure that you have installed the editable version of pydroid `./install_pydroid_editable.py` as per their [README](https://github.com/raaron/pydroid/blob/master/dev/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [QPython3l](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3) as it allows this without any changing of a manifest.

Create a script, tap and hold on it, and there you go. It will appear as a shortcut that when tapped will open a QPython3l terminal and run the script.